# why ejabberd not sending messages to client after receiving messages?

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am sending messages to an ejabbered server from an android device using the REST API **/api/send_message** and received successfully on the server-side but after receiving a message ejabberd server not sending to the client. I am sending a message from client like this:
`192.168.1.24:5443/api/send_message?"type"= "normal",&"from"= "admin@faiqkhan-Virtualbox",&"to"= "faiq@faiqkhan-Virtualbox",&"subject"= "Restart",&"body"="In 5 minutes"`
I also log on_user_send_packet lister on ejabberd and print data of the packet which shows the same as I send from the client.
I am using the smack library in android.
My server side module part where I received message:

```
on_user_send_packet({#message{from = From, body = Body, 
    subject = Subject} = Packet, C2SState}) ->
      ?INFO_MSG("mod_stanza_ack message packet: ~p~n", [Packet]),
      ?INFO_MSG("mod_stanza_ack message subject: ~p~n", [Subject]),
      ?INFO_MSG("mod_stanza_ack message body ignored: ~p~n", [Body])
    end,
    {Packet, C2SState}.
```

Server logs:

```
API call send_message [{<<"type">>,<<"normal">>},{<<"from">>,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d@faiqkhan-virtualbox">>},{<<"to">>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2@faiqkhan-virtualbox">>},{<<"subject">>,<<"Restart">>},{<<"body">>,<<"In 5 minutes">>}] from ::ffff:192.168.1.46:51597
13:43:14.298 [info] mod_stanza_ack message packet: {message,<<"4325851467592961166">>,normal,<<>>,{jid,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>},{jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>},[{text,<<>>,<<"Restart">>}],[{text,<<>>,<<"In 5 minutes">>}],undefined,[],#{}}
13:43:14.298 [info] mod_stanza_ack message subject: [{text,<<>>,<<"Restart">>}]
13:43:14.298 [info] mod_stanza_ack message body ignored: [{text,<<>>,<<"In 5 minutes">>}]
```

Trying to recevie message on client side using smack library's callback

```
public void newIncomingMessage(EntityBareJid from, Message message, Chat chat)
```

Did I miss some listeners on the client-side?

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly for me. I register accounts `admin` and `faiq`, login to `faiq` account with Tkabber client, then I send API query:

```
ejabberdctl send_message normal admin@localhost faiq@localhost Restart In5minutes
```

The client receives the message perfectly:

```
<message to='faiq@localhost'
    from='admin@localhost'
    id='18338888910541408674'>
  <archived by='faiq@localhost'
    id='1599730686404819'
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/>
  <stanza-id by='faiq@localhost'
    id='1599730686404819'
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:sid:0'/>
  <body>In5minutes</body>
  <subject>Restart</subject>
</message>
```

You can login with a well known Jabber desktop client, like Gajim or Psi, to check if your API call works correctly. That way you will know if the problem is in your client, or where...

Comment: Received message on Psi user. Finding issues on the android client side.